# data sync from rails with iphone sqlite db

Tags: iphone, performance, sqlite, import

I'm wondering whether there is a bossibility to export some selected data from my rails mysql db to a other sqlite db. The aim is to send that sqlite file directly to my iPhone application... That way I don't have to do a lot of xml integration in the iPhone app. That seems to be very slow...

Markus